# Git - Heroku deploy app that is composed of a couple of git repos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Recently I built an rails app for a local business.  They like this app so much that they've gotten a couple of other local businesses interested in having their own version of the app.

Here lies the problem that Im uncertain how to fix.  The core business logic behind the app would be the same for these new and future customers(about 80% of the code). Whereas each customer would have their own static pages, as well as their own stylesheets.

Ive thought about multi-tenancy, but these guys are picky enough that it honestly seems easier to build the app function the way they want, as opposed to building around DB stored customer preferences(perhaps I'm wrong here).

I would like configure this application so that I can push changes to the core business logic without overwriting the customer specific portions of the site.  Perhaps creating a second repo which only contains the customer specific content.

How do I configure this app/Git repo so that I can personalize the app without creating a bunch of parallel repos?

Comment: You should distill your core logic into a Gem that can be used by each site

Comment: Agree with meager's comment above. If you are not going the multi-tenant route, you should definitely go with one repo for each client. And using a gem/plugin for core logic will make it easier on you in the long run. By the way, congrats on building something for one client that got you multiple clients! Maybe you should think about turning it into a SaaS product.

Comment: @meagar thanks for your great recommendation. If you turn your comment into an answer Ill mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) pointed out the solution to this scenario is to encapsulate the core business logic of these applications into a Gem that can be reused later down the road.